# Asana and SVN Integration

Tags: git, svn, asana, post-commit

Asana has an API out which they are calling their "REST" api.
https://blog.asana.com/2012/04/announcing-the-asana-api/

Some people have made a post-commit script for git which allows you to add a "#task-id" into the message section when you make a commit and that will add a comment into the Asana task which adds your message from the commit and also provides a link to the code file.

Has anyone done this for SVN? I can't seem to find anything online however I thought I would ask first before spending a ton of time trying to make something for SVN and/or trying to learn git and adding their post commit script.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found a solution yet, bugify wrote a py script that creates a JSON object they send to their API (which comments/closes... bugs). You need to download their product to see what they've done (the script comes with the tar - basic account is free). I don't think their license authorizes you to use their code but if you know some python you can look at the script and then write your own that connects to asana API instead, with the correct parameters.  Really from what I see it is really simple, and the example gives you the name of the  functions to call to get the POST data (Mostly they are using subprocess.Popen). http://support.bugify.com/kb/integrations/getting-started-with-scmvcs-integration.